# Rails searching through array column and SQL injection

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have quick question. Is this code is vulnerable to SQL injection:

```
ActiveAdmin::SurveyPack.where("survey_schemas @> '{#{survey_schema}}'")
```

survey_schemas column is an array column in my rails app.

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sql-injection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make it simple.

```
    ActiveAdmin::SurveyPack.where("survey_schemas @> ARRAY[?]", survey_schema)
```

or

```
    ActiveAdmin::SurveyPack.where("survey_schemas = ARRAY[?]", survey_schema)
```

Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

short answer, yes.

from `ActiveAdmin::SurveyPack.where("survey_schemas @> '{#{survey_schema}}'")`

to `ActiveAdmin::SurveyPack.where("survey_schemas @> '{?}'", survey_schema)`

Comment: Hmm, this ActiveAdmin::SurveyPack.where("survey_schemas @> '{?}'", survey_schema)

returns syntax error.

Comment: Something like this works properly:
ActiveAdmin::SurveyPack.where("survey_schemas @> ?", '{"#{survey_schema}"}')