# Rails find substring in jsonb multiple where conditions

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, jsonb

Let's say I have the table `recipes` with the column `ingredients`, `jsonb` column type.
Example record:

```
{
  id: 1,
  ingredients: [
    'eggs',
    'fragrant bread',
    'fresh tomatoes'
  ]
}
```

How can I retrieve the record with substring in `where` conditions?
For example:

```
ingredients = ['egg', 'tomato']
Recipe.where('ingredients ?& array[:keys]', keys: ingredients)
```

I was trying:

```
ingredients = ['egg', 'tomato']
Recipe.where("ingredients @> ARRAY[?]::varchar[]", ingredients).count
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: jsonb @> character varying[] (PG::UndefinedFunction)
```

Comment: You can simply cast array to text then search with `[I]LIKE`. 

e.g. `SELECT * FROM (SELECT '["eggs", "with meatballs", "balls without meat"]'::text as col) foo where col ILIKE '%eat%'`. Injecting that query to rails should be easy. Plz let me know if that works for you.

Comment: @spirito_libero please checkout this https://stackoverflow.com/a/34060269/5580690 . Hope you will find this helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would really consider just using two tables instead as this stinks of the unnesiccary JSON antipattern.

```
class Recipe
  has_many :recipe_ingredients
  has_many :recipes, through: :recipe_ingredients

  def self.with_ingredients(*ingredients)
    binds = Array.new(ingredients.length, '?')
    sql = "ingredients.name ILIKE ANY(ARRAY[#{binds.join(,)}])"
    joins(:ingredients)
      .where(
        sql,
        *ingredients.map { |i| "'%#{i}%'" }
      )
  end
end
```

```
class RecipeIngredient
  belongs_to :ingredient
  belongs_to :recipe
end
```

```
class Ingredient
  has_many :recipe_ingredients
  has_many :recipes: through: :recipe_ingredients
end
```

This lets you use an effective index on `recipies.name`, sane queries and avoids denormalization.